# Firebird query - numbers only

Tags: node.js, firebird, phone-number

I'm doing a Firebird SQL query in which the column_type is **VARCHAR** and it's about phone numbers. The query is executing in my *nodeJS* app. The database has results like:

- 00-234-567
- 12/239-344
- +388-13123/323
- etc.

But I want the result in the format which contains numbers only. So only the

> 123321232

format can be accepted. I want the result to be formatted by the query, not in the node js. I've readed some topics about **rtrim** but it's replace by trim now which wouldn't allow this? Casting as a numeric type would be probably an ultimate fail. What would be a valid solution here?

EDIT: I've found some informations, but I'm still not sure if that would be valid. Query:

```
CASE 
  WHEN S.TELEFON SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+' THEN CAST(S.TELEFON AS INTEGER) 
  ELSE ''
  END
    AS PHONE
```

Comment: A telephone number is not an integer, don't try to treat it as such (eg in my country area codes start with a zero, casting to integer drops that zero), and with the international dialing code it will be too big to fit in a 32 bit integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use the [`REPLACE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-replace.html) function to replace all the non-numbers with empty string:

```
select
  replace(
    replace(
      replace(S.TELEFON, ' ', ''), -- space
    '-', ''),
  '/', '') AS phone
from mytab S
```

It's ugly and only works when you have limited number of different characters you need to get rid off (and which you know beforehand).

Comment: There are two commas missing. Every replace() function requires two arguments, separated with ','   ...anyway thank you. A good solution for now.